# Python Flask: Highlight word at Exact Position

Tags: python, html, for-loop, flask, highlight

I want to highlight specific texts from a message (data). Initially. I tried to create the list (ls) I want to highlight and use the code:

```
for word in ls:
        data = data.replace(word,'<mark style="background: #00ced1"> %s</mark>' %word)
```

The problem with this code is it will highlight all the repeated words, but I just want word at exact position to be highlighted.

I found the starting position and ending position with .start and .end code respectively. How do I use the information to repetitively highlight selected words in Python Flask?

Comment: by start and end do you mean you have started and ending position of each word that you want to highlight?

Comment: conver string to list and then used indexes and `.join` to separtate `no_color_text - color_text - non_color_text` (depending on indexes) and then address each one differently so like: `''.joind(no_color_text) + '<html tag>' + ''.join(color_text) + '</html tag>' + ''.join(no_color_text)` (a simple version)